# Can I do Unit Testing for non-void methods with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I tried to research on how to do unit testing with ReSharper for C# on Visual Studio for methods that are non void types, but to no avail. ReSharper only detects void methods.

Is there any way to reduce writing a void method to call the other methods with a return type? In this way, it can reduce time spent and increase efficiency.

My friend wants to do it without requiring much effort to generate the code, which also means that he does not need to write th eI know it can be done.

I tried looking through the 'Options' for ReSharper in changing the method type to allow non-void methods, but still am unable to find.

Can anyone explain to me if it this is possible/not possible?
Thank you so much : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ReShaper are you using? And what test-framework are you using?

I user ReShaper 5.1 and NUnit and this for example works for me:

```
[TestCase(true, Result="contentArea-wide")]
[TestCase(false, Result="contentArea")]
public string LoadView_PopulateContent_ContentCssClassIsSet(bool hideLeftNavigation) {
    var mvpFaker = this.CreateMvpFaker().CreatePresenter();
    mvpFaker.View.HideLeftNavigation = hideLeftNavigation;
    mvpFaker.LoadView();
    return mvpFaker.Model.Content.CssClass;
}
```

Is that the thing you want to do?

Comment: yes i want to do it like that. wow okay! but i don't understand the **contentArea-wide** portion. i am using ReSharper 5.0 and NUnit as well. cause i realised that the settings cant be changed on this.

Comment: oh I just realized that the content wide is your input. Btw I tried this, but I can't write 'TestCase' for mine. Is there a special configuration you have? I'm using nunit 2.1 as I am doing it from work and they don't allow an updated version.. But using ReSharper 5.0